# Rails partial view repeat display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, erb

Here is part of  my `index.html`

```
<div class="col-md-8">
        <% @books.each do |book| %>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <%= image_from_amazon(book.amazon_id) %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h3 class = "text-info">
                   <%= book.title %>
                </h3>
                 <br>
                <em class ="text-muted">
                    written by <%= book.author %>
                </em>
                <br>
                 <br>
                <p>
                    <%= book.description %>
                </p>
                <% book.genres.each do |genres| %> 
                    <span class="label label-primary">
                     <%= genres.name %> 
                    </span>
                    &nbsp
                <% end %>
              </div>
           </div>  
        <% end %>
        </div>
```

Basically, it will display 3 books, and it works fine.

Then, I move that code into `_book.html.erb` and edit above code into

```
<%= render @books %>
```

However, it repeat 3 times, that is, it display 9 books. And the sequence is [1st,2nd,3rd] [1st,2nd,3rd] [1st,2nd,3rd] like this picture.
[image]

### Update

update **index.html.erb**

```
 <div class="clearfix">
   <div class="col-md-12">
     <%= render @books %>

          <div class="col-md-4">
              <h3>Genre (Click to filter books)</h3>
              <br>
             <li>
             <span class = 'label label-danger'>
              <%= link_to "No filter" ,books_path, style: 'color:#FFFFFD' %>
             </span>
             <br>
             <br>
             </li>

              <% @genres.each do |genres| %>
              <li>
                <span class = 'label label-primary'  style="color:#FFFFFD">
                  <%= link_to genres.name ,books_path(filter: genres.name),style: 'color:#FFFFFD' %>
                </span>
              </li>
              <br>
              <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- clearfix -->
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste your updated `index.html.erb`? Is it just `<div class="col-md-8"><%= render @books %></div>`?

Comment: `@books.uniq` did you try it

Comment: I updated my question. And `@books.uniq` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render @books %>
</div>
```

And make sure `<% @books.each do |book| %>` and its `<% end %>` tag aren't in the partial.

[Rendering Collections Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections)

**Edit**

```
#index.html.erb
<div class="col-md-8">
    <%= render @books %>
</div>

# _book.html.erb
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= image_from_amazon(book.amazon_id) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3 class = "text-info">
            <%= book.title %>
        </h3>
        <br>
        <em class ="text-muted">
            written by <%= book.author %>
        </em>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p>
            <%= book.description %>
        </p>
        <% book.genres.each do |genres| %> 
        <span class="label label-primary">
            <%= genres.name %> 
        </span>
        &nbsp
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so, like this ?  `<div class="col-md-8">
    <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= render @books %>
   <% end %>
</div>`

Comment: It seems not work,either. Why I can't put `.each` and `end` tags in the partial file?

Comment: No, you don't need the each call anywhere if you render a collection.

Comment: wow, it work perfectly. So, if I render a collection called `books`, I don't need to put `@books.each` in the partial. Thanks, you have been a great help.